# Keep git repository updated

Tags: git, git-merge, git-pull

I'm still confused with all Git options :-(
I have a local repository and I want to update it on a daily basis with latest on a branch.
There are no changes in it so I just ran this every day

```
git pull origin develop
```

but for some reason I get this error so I guess pull is a bad option, I also don't want to delete and clone it every day

```
error: Pulling is not possible because you have unmerged files.
hint: Fix them up in the work tree, and then use 'git add/rm <file>'
hint: as appropriate to mark resolution and make a commit.
fatal: Exiting because of an unresolved conflict.
```

Which command I should use ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you have some local changes that are not yet committed. Given the fact that you are pulling, there are two possibilities:

1. You have done some local changes which were not committed
2. On the remote copy of the repo some commits were being done which cannot be automatically merged with the changes you have

To solve this issue, first run

```
git status
```

See whether it's a merge issue. If not, then you can decide to [stash](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash) your local changes, commit them or `git reset --hard` to roll back.

If, on the other hand, it's a merge conflict, then you will need to compare the versions and fix each merge conflict separately. Read more here: https://www.simplilearn.com/tutorials/git-tutorial/merge-conflicts-in-git

Answer (score 0):

Git informs you that you have local changed files. Try

```
git pull --autostash
```